# ng-transclude error when using md-button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

I am using md-button in the following way:

```
<md-button aria-label="edit"  target-mode="edit" style="z-index: 9;right: 10px; top: 10px; position: absolute;"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </md-button>
```

and am getting the following error:

```
Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template!
No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. 
Element: <button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" aria-label="show" target-mode="show" style="z-index: 9;right: 10px; top: 10px; position: absolute;">
```

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening for a while - maybe someone out there has had this before?

BTW - the ng-transclude you see in the error is automatically inserted somehow.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by removing ng-app from my index screen.